# WordPress pods template: Override title before get_header()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a pods page using a template, and it's working great. But I just need to override the title tag with a pods field containing a value:

```
    $parcours = pods('parcours', pods_v_sanitized(3, 'url'));

    $seo_title = $parcours->field('seo_title');

    // Supposed override
    function custom_page_title($seo_title) {

        return $seo_title;
    }

    add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'custom_page_title', 999, 1);

    get_header();

?>
```

The title does not appear on the page (no override). Of course I made sure that `$seo_title` actually has a value.

Am I missing something or this is not doable that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use the `$seo_title` variable in the function as a [`global`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Your code will work if you use it like this:

```
$parcours = pods('parcours', pods_v_sanitized(3, 'url'));

global $seo_title;
$seo_title = $parcours->field('seo_title');

// Supposed override
function custom_page_title() {
    global $seo_title;

    return $seo_title;
}

add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'custom_page_title', 999);

get_header(); ?>
```

With the line `global $seo_title;`, we are calling the variable, which is out of the function:

```
$seo_title = $parcours->field('seo_title');
```

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right about the scope, but unfortunately the title meta remains unchanged

Comment: I tried the code and it's working. your problem is with first 2 lines. add `var_dump($seo_title);` after this line `$seo_title = $parcours->field('seo_title'); ` and you'll get emty string, null, false or something like that

Comment: Thanks yes i had a typo int the var name but now Variable exist as a string ( eg string(42) "Randonnée dans le Sahara marocain - Maroc") but the title is not overriden, am i using the right hook ?

Comment: I looked at code provided. I missed to declare the `$seo_title` as `global` out of function scope.Updated the answer. I tested the code, and all is working ok. let me know, if it don't, just because there may be some plugin/code, which will change `title` tag in the later firing `filters`

Comment: Indeed ! Great txs !

Comment: thanks a ton. the 999 is what it really made it work for me.